# usage of useEffect blanks out page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Pretty much the title, when I add

```js
   useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const result = await fetch('http://localhost.com/ping');
      console.log(result)
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);
```

to my component, the page renders properly and then immediately blanks out. Not sure what I did wrong since it's literally the same in the [React Documentation](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-hooks-fetch-data).

Full component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useEffect } from 'react';
const Test = () => {

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const result = await fetch('http://localhost.com/ping');
      console.log(result)
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Test</h1>
    </>
  );
};

export default Test;
```

## App

```
import { hot } from 'react-hot-loader/root';
import React from 'react';
import Navigation from './components/Navigation/Navigation.jsx';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <div>Stuff</div>
      <Navigation></Navigation>
    </>
  );
};
export default hot(App);
```

## Navigation

```js
/* eslint-disable react/display-name */
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import React from 'react';
import Home from './Home';
import Login from './Login';
import Logout from './Logout';
import Faq from './Faq';
import Dashboard from './Dashboard';
import Test from './Test';

const Navigation = () => {
  const isLoggedIn = false;
  return (
    <>
      <Router>
        <div>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <Link to='/'>Home</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              {isLoggedIn ? (
                <Link to='/auth/logout'>Logout</Link>
              ) : (
                <Link to='/auth/login'>Login</Link>
              )}
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to='/auth/dashboard'>Dashboard</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to='/faq'>FAQ</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to='/test'>Test</Link>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path='/'>
            <Home />
          </Route>
          <Route exact path='/auth/login'>
            <Login />
          </Route>
          <Route path='/auth/logout'>
            <Logout />
          </Route>
          <Route path='/auth/dashboard'>
            <Dashboard />
          </Route>
          <Route path='/faq'>
            <Faq />
          </Route>
          <Route path='/test'>
            <Test />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </>
  );
};

export default Navigation;
```

I have to write some stuff here because stack overflow decided that i am not allowed to post the code that people asked for ...

Comment: have you checked your console? maybe fetch is throwing an unhandled exception and crashes! Add `...fetch('http://localhost.com/ping').catch(console.error)`

Comment: @TobiasLins console is clean

Comment: I think the url is `http://localhost/ping` not `.com`

Comment: @Sohail yes, made a typo there ^^
Still blanks out ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After poking around a bit I finally got an error message : `"Test.jsx:26 Uncaught ReferenceError: regeneratorRuntime is not defined"`
To fix that install regenerator-runtime and require it globally. Read the [readme](https://www.npmjs.com/package/regenerator-runtime) of regenerator-runtime if you are unsure on how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap the fetch call in try/catch block to run your code smoothly.

And use one react import instead of two separate.

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react';

const Test = () => {

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try{
        const result = await fetch('http://localhost/ping');
        console.log(result)
      } catch(error) {
          console.log(error.message);
      }

    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Test</h1>
    </>
  );
};

export default Test;
```

Comment: no errors have been caught :(
even when there is nothing to do inside the useEffect, just a console.log() it breaks ...

Comment: And use one react import instead of two separate.

Comment: didn't see that autoimport decided to import react in multiple lines, doesn't make a difference though

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209629/discussion-between-sohail-and-twiggeh).

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
   useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
          const result = await fetch('http://localhost.com/ping');
          console.log(result)
      } catch (e){
        console.log(e)
      }
    };
    fetchData();
  });
```

Instead of

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const result = await fetch('http://localhost.com/ping');
      console.log(result)
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);
```

Comment: You don't need those **[ ]** as the second param in you useEffect()

Comment: Doesn't make a difference, still loads for 1 frame and then blank page :(

Comment: There might be something with your app.js. Works fine on blank project, just tested